# What happens when I request WRITE_STORAGE in Android 11?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11, scoped-storage

I upgraded my app to API 30 recently. I used Mediastore to handle all of my image and video files (Scoped storage), no longer depend on WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. But I forgot to restrict the permission to 28.
So instead of this,

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="28">
```

It looks like this

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
```

We aren't releasing a new version of the app until Nov 1,2021 which is Google's deadline for all the apps to be in API 30. My question is, Will there be an issue on Nov 1 as I didn't add `android:maxSdkVersion` in my Manifest file or will it be ignored?

Comment: It should be 29. Not 28. Further i think you should just use the permissiin without a max.

Comment: Even if I don't `requestExternalLegacyStorage`, should it be 29? 
I referred here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65477206/980898 and here
https://www.raywenderlich.com/9577211-scoped-storage-in-android-10-getting-started

Comment: You should always request legacy external storage. Its needed for if your app gets installed on an Android 10 device. Well.. if the code uses external storage. And i think it does.

Comment: After some rethinking i think you should use it and set to 29. Are you requesting for runtime permission confirmation? It will be used to not ask on 30 i think. But i doubt.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps, do you know if this is mandatory? Or is it ok if I didn't add in Android 11