# Flutter: File can not be deleted or can not change path of the file

Tags: android, flutter, file, delete-file, internal-storage

I tried to change path of the internal storage file but it could not happen.
Then I tried copy that file to another location and delete it from first location. unfortunately, this also did not work.

Here is my error:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot delete file, path =
> '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_20230116-114448.jpg'
> (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

If anyone have idea then it could be helpful. Thank You.

Comment: and what is the output of this command: `adb shell ls -l /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_20230116-114448.jpg`?

Comment: is showing "permission denied" . Any solution to enable permission?.

Comment: what about parent folders like `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots` or `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM` etc?

Comment: from the "/storage/emulated/ " I get permission denied error.

Comment: and can you list those folders from your app? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory/listSync.html

Comment: I got [Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.packagename/files/.hidden_media'].

Answer (score 2):

If you are in android 10 and above WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is remove in android native...we can only delete the file that app have write in DCIM or any public directory, if we uninstall the app and reinstall the same app then it won't delete it...
You can view the answer and comment of this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221188/write-external-storage-when-targeting-android-10)

Answer (score 0):

before accessing the storage ask for storage permission with the below code and also you can check this permission package https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler. Don't forget to add permission in for android and iOS in their respective folder

```
await Permission.storage.request();
```

and if you have any other doubt then you can ask it in comments.

Comment: I have already asked permission for storage and I get File path successfully but can not write or delete from the storage.

Comment: have you added this android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in this application tag <application
        android:label="app name"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
       >   and for permissions add all of this three <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Yes, I have added. I can access all storage photos and videos but can not delete only.

Comment: how you are deleting it can share that code snippet