# How to implement file picker android 11

Tags: android, android-11, filepicker

Can anyone please share complete solution for File Picker in Android 11 for both Internal and External Storage

Comment: try this : https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage

Answer (score 0):

```
**For Single File**
// Request code for selecting a PDF document.
const val PICK_PDF_FILE = 2

fun openFile(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/pdf"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Here Code For Android 11 File Upload using Intent and also you dont have to mention MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission in AndroidManifest.xml file i have implemented without this permission.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    chooseFile.setType("application/pdf");
                    chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
                    startActivityForResult(chooseFile, Constants.REQUEST_PICK_FILE);
                }else{
String[] types = new String[]{"pdf"};
    FilePickerBuilder.getInstance().setMaxCount(UPLOAD_LIMIT - attachmentModelList.size())
            .setActivityTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
            .setActivityTitle(mActivity.getString(R.string.select_documents))
            /*.sortDocumentsBy(SortingTypes.NAME)*/
            .enableDocSupport(false)
            .addFileSupport("PDF", types)
            /*.setSelectedFiles(masterList !!)*/
            .pickFile(this);
}
```

here is onActivityResult Code Pick File Name and other information

```
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_PICK_FILE &&
                        resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    String mimeType = getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(uri);
                    String filename;
                    if (mimeType == null) {
                        String path = CommonMethod.getPath(getActivity(), uri);
    //                    if (path == null) {
    //                        filename = FilenameUtils.getName(uri.toString());
    //                    } else {
                        File file = new File(path);
                        filename = file.getName();
    //                    }
                    } else {
                        Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                        Cursor returnCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
                        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                        filename = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
                        String size = Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex));
                    }
                    File fileSave = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
                    String sourcePath = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null).toString();
                    File targetFile = null;
                    try {
                        targetFile = new File(sourcePath + "/" + filename);
                        boolean success = CommonMethod.copyFileStream(new File(sourcePath + "/" + filename), uri, getActivity());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (targetFile != null) {
                        String fileName = Utils.getFileName(getActivity(),Uri.fromFile(targetFile));
 String filePath = targetFile.getPath();
    
                       
                }
```